# Do PNG images slow down the render of an html?

Tags: html, png

I'm using several PNG images (via CSS) into a site's template, xhtml and CSS,.

I've kept the pngs as small as possible, and optimised as possible, but when testing it in any browser (Safari, Firefox, IEs) it takes at least 2 seconds to render.

Unfortunately I can't share the code here, but I can say that I've removed all javascript and my html code is fairly small (about 250 lines and no tables) and validates correctly.

I would like to know if the PNGs are the "guilty" part as this is my first site done almost exclusively with pngs (instead of gifs + jpegs) (I won't support IE6 so no need for hacks).

Comment: I would check several things first: try in different browsers and check if you see the same behavior. Check maybe the server render PNG differently e.g. gzipping while it's not needed. Try having the `PNG` directly in image tag rather than loaded via CSS background.

Comment: How many PNG do you loead? Do you use CSS sprite?

Comment: yes I'm using CSS sprites but that could optimised as well, even so, I'm using about 11 pngs via CSS and these take less than 40Kb; I've tested it in several browsers and I forgot to mention this was on a straightforward test, no server, just testing a html.

Comment: edit: it appears that it is indeed loading more than 11 pngs :( it is loading an average of 44 images (mix of CSS and ones on the html), it may be my computer that needs a retirement, but at least I've been "nelightened" about the PNGs not slowing down by themselfs but (probably) by the number of requests, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, they do not take time to render (unless you have a really slow computer). What does take time, is the retrieving of a lot of small files. When you query a web-server for a small file, the time retrieving the file itself does not take long. But to setup the connection etc. etc. adds up.

So, what you should do, is to make what is called a "sprite". Combine all the small images to one large and "cut" them with CSS. How it is done and what it is exactly is explained here:

http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/

and here

http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/04/27/the-mystery-of-css-sprites-techniques-tools-and-tutorials/

Answer (score 5):

If you have many images (doesn't have to be PNGs), then download times will be impacted. By default browsers have a limited number of threads to download content with (IIRC FF has 4), so the more images you have, the longer things will take.

Additionally, if you don't specify dimensions on your images, the browser can only correctly layout the page when an image arrives. It will need to reflow the layout for every such image, which is both expensive and time consuming.

In short, ensure you don't have too many images to download and that the HTML markup has the right dimensions for them.

One workaround for having many images is to use [CSS sprites](http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/).

Comment: Kudos re the dimensions. It's easier on the user, too, because the page doesn't keep shifting; I wish all websites would do it. Actually, I wish it were required by the spec.

Comment: upvoted for the dimensions tip, but in my case I do specify it when needed.

Answer (score 1):

Check this link. Read under the "Optimize Images" tab.

- [Best Practices for Speeding Up Your Web Site](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html)
- [Speed up Images Load Time](http://www.webweaver.nu/html-tips/load-time.shtml)

I hope this was the thing you needed.